# python json print empty value

Tags: python, json

When I print `banner["STATUS"]["Description"]`, I get an empty value?

```
banner = {
  "STATUS":[
    {
      "STATUS": "S",
      "When": 1470157636,
      "Code": 11,
      "Msg": "Summary",
      "Description": "nsgminer 0.9.2"
    }
  ],
  "SUMMARY": [
    {
      "Elapsed":1502,
      "MHS av":0.00,
      "Found Blocks":0,
      "Getworks":58,
      "Accepted":0,
      "Rejected":0,
      "Hardware Errors":0,
      "Utility":0.00,
      "Discarded":116,
      "Stale":0,
      "Get Failures":2,
      "Local Work":180,
      "Remote Failures":0,
      "Network Blocks":17,
      "Total MH":0.0000,
      "Work Utility":0.00,
      "Difficulty Accepted":0.00000000,
      "Difficulty Rejected":0.00000000,
      "Difficulty Stale":0.00000000,
      "Best Share":0
    }
  ],
  "id":1
}
```

Comment: `banner['STATUS'][0]['Description']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print banner['STATUS'][0]['Description'] # 0 will tell its the 0th index of the list
```

'Status' key holds a list. Since 'Description' is placed in the 1st dictionary in that list, [0] is needed to access the 1st dictionary.